# jquery load new vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, loadvars, variables

It´s posible , if i have one var , use jquery for load news vars and change these

For example if i have :

```
var activate_auto="yes";



$("#play").click(function() {

/// load vars
activate_auto="yes";


});


$("#stop").click(function() {

/// load vars
activate_auto="no";


});
```

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
<script>

var w_ac="900";
var h_ac="295";
var w_ac_col="64";
var n_cols="5";
var margin="3";
var time_ac_change=5000;
var time_ac_effects=2000;
var time_ac_hide_effects=1000;

var ac_activate_auto="si";
var ac_activate_auto_random="no";

var margin=margin*n_cols;
var result=w_ac_col*n_cols+margin;
var final=w_ac-result;


$(function(){




$("#ac_play").click(function() 
{
ac_activate_auto="si";
ac_activate_auto_random="no";
time_ac_change=2000;
});


$("#ac_stop").click(function() 
{
ac_activate_auto="no";
ac_activate_auto_random="no";
time_ac_change=2000000;
});


for (i=1;i<=n_cols;i++)
{

$(".ac_"+i+"").css("width",""+w_ac_col);

}

});


function acordeon(id)
{

$(function(){

for (i=1;i<=n_cols;i++)
{

if (+id==i)
{}
else
{
$(".ac_"+i+"_inf").hide(time_ac_hide_effects);
}

}

$(".ac_"+id+"_inf").css("width",""+final);
$(".ac_"+id+"_inf").show(time_ac_effects).fadeIn(time_ac_effects);

$(".ac_im").css("width",""+final);
$(".ac_im").css("height",""+h_ac);








});





}

</script>


<script>









var starting_slide = n_cols;

function setSlide(i) 
{


acordeon(i);















if (i > 0) {
i--;   
setTimeout( function(){setSlide(i)}, time_ac_change);

}

else 
{
setTimeout( function(){setSlide(starting_slide)}, 1000);
} 

}






if (ac_activate_auto=="si")
{
setSlide(starting_slide);
}






if (ac_activate_auto_random=="si")
{

$(document).ready(function(){

acordeon(1);

var refreshId = setInterval(function(){

var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*n_cols)    

if (r==0)
{
acordeon(1)
}
else
{
acordeon(+r)
}


}, time_ac_change);
});





}

</script>
```

In this case works always when i push over pay or stop but only one time , if i push over play works play but no works before stop and the same when the first i push it´s play

I want push stop load new var and play and other time load the other var , i don´t know if it´s possible , thank´s !

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. You are not 'loading' new vars - you are merely overwriting a var with a new value in some event callbacks. What precisely do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes thats right , i want load the same var with new value , because i want stop and play one function , if change the values to take the function i can create this effect , but when i push for example over the stop the function load new vars and stop but no works the play other time , but if reload the website and push over play the function yes take other time the other values of these vars but no works stop loading new vars , basically stop and play using new values based in new vars

Answer (score 0):

You should only create your var and don't set a value to it, and then, only set its values inside your functions. Ex.:

```
var activate_auto; // this is outside your click functions
```

Ok, now I'm not sure what you want to do... will edit it later if necessary =\

Comment: I want use click function for load new vars , this vars operate over function and this function take this values for works , when i push over stop or play i want change this load vars first for modificate the function and the values to take

Comment: I'm sorry Fran, but I really don't know what you mean. If you need to 'set' new vars inside your functions, on click, you can simply cast a new var with a different name and set it's value. If you mean that you want to take one value, from one var, and give this value to your 'activate_auto' var, you can do so using activate_auto = my_other_var; In this case you're setting the 'activate_auto' var with the 'my_other_var' value.

Comment: I create slider that use automatic mode you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736010/my-slider-no-works-automatic-mode , i want create play and stop functions for this code , i try but no get it , regards

Comment: Why didn't you accept @SharkyLV right answer on that topic? Anyway, what I think it's happening is that, after you click play for the "second time", you're indeed setting the 'activate_auto' var to true, but then nothing is working because you have to 'run' your slider function again, right after setting the activate_auto back to true, inside that function.

Comment: I modificate the post and now you can see the new code with the last changes here , regars